# django multiple databases in views

Tags: django

I am building a project which requires multiple database support. This has been relatively straightforward so far, as I can refer to the given database with aliases. For example a simple lookup uses the following view:

```
def index(request):
    article_count = Article.objects.using('mydb_2').count()
    return render_to_response('index.html',
        locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, I'm not sure how I implement the db alias reference with get_object_or_404. At the moment I have:

```
def article_detail(request, year, slug):
    return render_to_response('article_detail.html', {
        'article': get_object_or_404(Article, volume__year__exact=year, slug=slug),
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just looking at the code for `get_object_or_404` I **think** you may be able to do:

```
get_object_or_404(Article.objects.using('mydb_2'), volume__year__exact=year, slug=slug);
```

Comment: Not a problem... happy to help.